# Sphinx Search How can I search above the certain date

Tags: python, search-engine, sphinx

I  have a code :

```
def set_date_range_filter(self,attribute = None,start_date = None , end_date = None):
    if attribute is None:
        return
    #Make sure set the passing start date and end date
    if not start_date or not end_date :
        return 
    if isinstance(start_date, str) :
        start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    if isinstance(start_date, unicode) :
        start_date = datetime.strptime(str(start_date), "%Y-%m-%d")
    if isinstance(end_date ,str):
        end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    if isinstance(end_date ,unicode):
        end_date = datetime.strptime(str(end_date), "%Y-%m-%d")

    # Shphnx Range Filter ,start_date and end_date must be integers that define the acceptable attribute values range

    start_date = int(time.mktime(start_date.timetuple()))
    end_date = int(time.mktime(end_date.timetuple()))
    if start_date > end_date :
        return 
    self.sphinx.SetFilterRange(str(attribute),start_date,end_date)
```

I want to update this code to accept only 'start_date' or only 'end_date' or both.

Like i want all date from 2014-01-01 or i want all data after 2014-01-01
or say i want all data from 2014-01-01 to 2014-09-01. how can i archive this ??

Answer (score 1):

Rather than

```
if not start_date or not end_date :
    return
```

replace with say

```
if not start_date:
    start_date = '1971-01-01'
if not end_date:
    end_date = '2037-01-01'
```

Or similar. If either are missing, then just use a very early, or very late dates (outside the range of your data). Example dates above choosen within range of unix timestamps.

(will then be turned into proper date objects via strptime)